# How to display facebook username in our website url?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to display facebook username on my website's URL like this "http://localhost:8080/testing/home.jsp?user=fbuser" but the result return null. This is my first time to do with facebook.May I know is there any solution to get the value? I tried to find the solution but can't seem to find the correct answer.

Here what I have so far.

```
function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome! Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me?fields=name',function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: '+ response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, '
                                    + response.name + '!';
          <button>Logout</button></span>';
                            document.getElementById('response.name').innerHTML = response.name;
                            jQuery.post("SavePage.jsp", {
                                name : response.id
                            }, function(data) {
                                alert("Response: " + response.name);
                            });
                        });
    }
```

Comment: did you authorize the user? without authorization, there is no data. check out my answer.

Comment: @luschn yes. I already authorize the user using function statusChangeCallback(response){} . and I also tried your code but doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn´t work" is not a sufficient error description. please be more specific. debug your code properly by using console.log(response) at the beginning of the callback.

Comment: @luschn after I first login using facebook account, the username is displayed but when I send the value to another page, I am getting a null value

Comment: that´s some weird code anyway, why is there a button html tag in the middle of the callback function?

Comment: do you have a testlink on a real server?

Comment: @luschn no. I don't have that. what is that for?

Comment: it would be easier for us to test

Comment: @luschn I already figured out. I shouldn't put jquery.post inside the code because the response is duplicated. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to authorize the user. Use [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) to do that:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user just authorized your app
    }
}, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/